# different number of columns in tcbitemize

Tags: positioning, subfig

I use the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{subfig} %For subcaptions

\newcommand{\mysubfig}[3][width=\linewidth]{%
    \tcbitem\subfloat[#2]{\includegraphics[#1]{#3}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tcbitemize}[
    raster columns=3,
    raster halign=center,
    raster every box/.style={blankest}
    ]
\mysubfig{}{example-image-b}
\mysubfig{}{example-image-b}
\mysubfig{}{example-image-b}
\mysubfig{}{example-image-b}
\mysubfig{}{example-image-b}
\mysubfig{}{example-image-b}
\mysubfig{}{example-image-b}
\mysubfig{}{example-image-b}
\mysubfig{}{example-image-b}

\end{tcbitemize}

\caption{Figure caption}
\label{pics:blablabla}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: code results]

But I want the figures will ordered by columns, not rows. Meaning:

[image]

How can I do it? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on examples in the [`tcolorbox` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf), section 15.6.1 Raster Setup, page 305.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{subfig} %For subcaptions

\newcommand{\mysubfig}[3][width=\linewidth]{%
    \tcbitem\subfloat[#2]{\includegraphics[#1]{#3}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{tcbitemize}[
    raster columns=3, 
    raster equal height=none, 
    raster column skip=2em, 
    raster every box/.style={blankest}
  ]
    \tcbitem
    \begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=1]
      \mysubfig{}{example-image-b}
      \mysubfig{}{example-image-b}
      \mysubfig{}{example-image-b}
    \end{tcbitemize}
    \tcbitem
    \begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=1, raster row skip=2em]
      \mysubfig{}{example-image-b}
      \mysubfig{}{example-image-b}
    \end{tcbitemize}
    \tcbitem
    \begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=1, raster row skip=2em]
      \mysubfig{}{example-image-b}
      \mysubfig{}{example-image-b}
    \end{tcbitemize}
  \end{tcbitemize}
  \caption{Figure caption}
  \label{pics:blablabla}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I can offer an implementation based on `\valign`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig} %For subcaptions
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcommand{\mysubfig}[3][width=\linewidth]{%
  \subfloat[#2]{\includegraphics[#1]{#3}}%
}
\newenvironment{columnsofimages}[1]
 {%
  \setlength{\linewidth}{\dimexpr(\columnwidth-\columnsep*\numexpr(#1-1)\relax)/3\relax}%
  \def\\{\cr\noalign{\hskip\columnsep}}%
  \xpretocmd{\mysubfig}{\hbox\bgroup}{}{}%
  \xapptocmd{\mysubfig}{\egroup}{}{}%
  \valign\bgroup\vfil##\vfil\cr
 }
 {\crcr\egroup}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\begin{columnsofimages}{3}
\mysubfig{}{example-image-b}
\mysubfig{}{example-image-b}
\mysubfig{}{example-image-b}\\
\mysubfig{}{example-image-b}
\mysubfig{}{example-image-b}\\
\mysubfig{}{example-image-b}
\mysubfig{}{example-image-b}
\end{columnsofimages}

\caption{Figure caption}
\label{pics:blablabla}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The primitive `\valign` is similar to `\halign` but does columns rather than rows. The trick is to enclose the `\subfloat` commands inside `\hbox{...}`, which can be done without a new macro, by locally patching `\mysubfig`.

The setting to `\linewidth` is: subtract `\columnsep` times one less than the number of columns and divide by the number of columns. Then `\\` will insert `\columnsep` between any two columns.

[image]